# Module-wide destructor in Python?

Tags: python, logging, destructor

I am wondering if there is a module-wide destructor such that we can make use of it to finalize or call some specific *shut down* functions in a module?

For example, some handlers of the module **logbook** are created and pust into the stack (ex, `handler1.push_application()` and it is better to *pop up* those handlers when your program exit. It would be great to have some sort of *automatically* function-calls to do this and *module-wide destructor* is one of possible candidates I can think :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`atexit` module](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) allows you to register cleanup functions that Python will perform on interpreter termination.